# Disable 'Leave site?' popup when close Orbeon Form window

Tags: popupwindow, orbeon

We have some Orbeon forms and do not want Orbeon to save our Control Values because we send those in a POST method as xml. We replaced 'then save' line with 'then send' line in the properties-local.xml file. But when we click on Submit button (and get xml successfully) and we close Orbeon window, a 'Leave site? Changes you made may not be saved.' popup appears.
Is there a way to disable this popup?

The related part of our properties-local.xml:

```
<property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.detail.process.submit.myappname.*">
    require-uploads
    then validate-all
    then send(uri="http://myuri", method="POST", content="xml")
    then new-to-edit
    then success-message("save-success")
    recover error-message("database-error")
</property>
```

Comment: Could edit your question to also include the property that you have in your `properties-local.xml` that defines the process you are referring to? (And then if possible, also post a follow up comment here, so we get a notification.) -Alex

Comment: I edited my question and insert the related part of the properties-local.xml file (for submit, the situation is similar for save).

Comment: Got it, thank you for the process, and I've posted an answer below. I hope it helps. -Alex

Comment: Did you get a chance to try adding the `set-data-status(status = "safe")` action to your process? If so, did that work for you? -Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your process, before the line that starts with `recover`, add:

```
set-data-status(status = "safe")
```

For on this action, see [its documentation](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/advanced/buttons-and-processes/actions-form-runner#set-data-status).